# No shadow after render

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I'm new to blender and have only spent about two hours on it.

1. I drew an animation and it went out just fine in preview, however after I rendered it, all shadows are gone (shadows below the object & shadow of the object) which made my animation of the block flat
2. I only set the background plane orange but the whole output seems to be filled with some orange atmosphere

What am I doing wrong?

[image: what I thought the object may look like]

[image: the actual output]

Blender 2.8 on MacOS

Comment: Hi, there is more info missing. Upload your file, post your settings or so. It is just guessing why there is no shadows. What is your light source? What render are you using?

Comment: how do I upload files?

Comment: I'm using a point light and Eevee render

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your material node? I suspect you may have created a shadeless material by accident.

Comment: [How to upload blend files](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links)

Comment: Tks here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EE4eewpoqhscb2G423xdf0UHluyBvw5d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I made some changes but still can't see shadows on the object

Answer (score -1):

I seems that your light source is just your world. It wont give you much shadow. Try to set your world in darker and add some lamps. Or you can also change your world to an HDRI.

Comment: I do have one lamp lit, is it not enough?